# Internet zone with Anonymous - Search Results web part having error when click on Next page. No error in the default zone with windows authentication

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, anonymous-authentication

Culture_Client::Constructing CultureInfo from '-1' failed: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Positive number required.  Parameter name: culture
 at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.set_Culture_Client(Int32 value)

================================================================

Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The current user does not have permissions to create a QueryProperties template from "querygroup://webroot/Pages/Home.aspx?groupname=c6011e14-4deb-43d9-8aae-22a90a40dc15".
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ResultsWebPartQueryPropertiesTemplateBuilder.Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.IQueryPropertiesTemplateBuilder.CheckPermissions()
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.OverlaySafeQueryPropertiesTemplate(Query query)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.PreExecuteQuery(Query query)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)

 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c_DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b_14()

 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement xe)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessExceptionHandlingScope(XmlElement xe)